# Most efficiently downloading, unzipping, and analyzing many files in Node JS

Tags: node.js, performance, download, zip

I have to download a large amount of compressed files onto my Node JS server from a third party host, unzip them, analyze them, and store them. These files are a little over 18000 XMLs, each between about 0.01 and 0.06mb. The files are split into 8 compressed folders of greatly varying size.

Right now, this is my process:

1. Download the compressed files using the `request` library

   `request({ url: fileUrl, encoding: null }, function(err, resp, body) {...});`
2. Write the downloaded files to a directory

   `fs.writeFile(output, body, function(err) {...});`
3. Unzip the downloaded material using `extract-zip` and place in a new directory

   `unzip(output, { dir : directory }, function (err) {...});`
4. Delete the downloaded zip file

   `fs.unlink('/a-directory/' + output, (err) => { if (err) console.log(err); });`
5. Get the items in the directory

   `fs.readdir(fromDir, function(err, items) {...});`
6. For each item (XML file), read it

   `fs.readFile(fromDir + '/' + item, 'utf8', function(err, xmlContents) {...});`
7. For each read XML file, convert it to a JSON

   `let bill = xmlToJsonParser.toJson(xmlContents)`
8. Will do some other stuff, but I haven't written that part yet

I can post more complete code if that would help anyone.

As you can see, there are a bunch of steps here, and I have a hunch that some of them can be removed or at least made more efficient.

What are your suggestions for improving the performance?––right now the process completes, but I hit 100% CPU every time, which I am fairly certain is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general guidelines for scaling this type of work:

1. Steps that are entirely async I/O scale really well in node.js.
2. When doing lots of I/O operations, you will want to be able to control how many are in-flight at the same time to control memory usage and TCP resource usage.  So, you probably would launch several hundred requests at a time, not 18,000 requests all at once.  As one finishes, you launch the next one.
3. Steps that use a meaningful amount of CPU should be in a process that you can run N of them (often as many as you have CPUs).  This helps your CPU usage work scale.
4. Try to avoid keeping more in memory than you need to.  If you can pipe something directly from network to disk, that can significantly reduce memory usage vs. buffer the entire file and then writing the whole thing to disk.
5. Figure out some way to manage a work queue of jobs waiting for the worker processes to run. You can either have your main app maintain a queue and use http to ask it for the next job or you can even work it all through the file system with lock files.

So, here are some more specifics based on these guidelines:

I'd say use your main server process for steps 1 and 2.  Neither of the first two steps are CPU intensive so a single server process should be able to handle a zillion of those.  All they are doing is async I/O.  You will have to manage how many `request()` operations are in flight at the same time to avoid overloading your TCP stack or your memory usage, but other than that, this should scale just fine since it's only doing async I/O.

You can reduce memory usage in steps 1 and 2 by piping the response directly to the output file so as bytes arrive, they are immediately written to disk without holding the entire file in memory.

Then write another node.js app that caries out steps 3 - 8 (steps 3 and perhaps 7 are CPU intensive).  If you write them in a way that they just "check out" a file from a known directory and work on it, you should be able to make it so that you can run as many of these processes as you have CPUs and thus gain scale while also keeping the CPU load away from your main process.

The check-out function can either be done via one central store (like a redis store or even just a simple server of your own that maintains a work queue) that keeps track of which files are available for work or you could even implement it entirely with file system logic using lock files.

> right now the process completes, but I hit 100% CPU every time, which I am fairly certain is bad.

If you only have one process and it's at 100% CPU, then you can increase scale by getting more processes involved.

> As you can see, there are a bunch of steps here, and I have a hunch that some of them can be removed or at least made more efficient.

Some ideas:

1. As mentioned before, pipe your request directly to the next operation rather than buffer the whole file.
2. If you have the right unzip tools, you could even pipe the request right to an unzipper which is piped directly to a file.  If you did this, you'd have to scale the main process horizontally to get more CPUs involved, but this would save reading and writing the compressed file to/from disk entirely.  You could conceivably combine steps 1-4 into one stream write with an unzip transform.
3. If you did the transform stream described in step 2, you would then have a separate set of processes that carry out steps 5-8.

Here are a couple libraries that can be used to combine pipe and unzip:

[unzip-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip-stream)

[node-unzip-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-unzip-2)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what library/etc. to use to unzip the file by parts instead of at once?

Comment: @Dopapp - I don't follow your specific unzip requirements (since you've provided no actual code).  I added a couple unzip libraries that works with streams and `.pipe()`.